# Creating Django form questionnaire with radio buttons

Tags: django, forms, radio-button

I'm attempting to implement a survey within my django application. Currently I have it implemented by manually drawing out the HTML for the form structure like so:

```
      <!-- Question 1-->
  <form method="post" action="{% url 'piuserform' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="mx-auto">
      <h3 class="mb-4">At the time of the accident, the injured party was: </h3>
      <label class="radcontainer">The driver of an automobile.
            <input type="radio" name="question1" value="The driver of an automobile">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
      <label class="radcontainer">The passenger of an automobile.
            <input type="radio" name="question1" value="The passenger of an automobile">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
      <label class="radcontainer">A pedestrian.
            <input type="radio" name="question1" value="A pedestrian">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
    </div>
    <!-- /Question 1 -->


    <!-- question 3-->
    <div class="mx-auto pt-5">
      <h3 class="mb-4">How many vehicles were involved in the accident?</h3>
      <label class="radcontainer">One
            <input type="radio" name="question3" value="One">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
      <label class="radcontainer">Two
            <input type="radio" name="question3" value="Two">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
      <label class="radcontainer">Three
            <input type="radio" name="question3" value="Three">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
      <label class="radcontainer">Four or more
            <input type="radio" name="question3" value="Four or more">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
    </div>
    <!-- /Question 3 -->
```

Now I tried to implement something to this effect using Django forms api but it would only render the last question. The questionnaire is all radio buttons with the answer fields varying greatly. Is there a way to automate this so I can possibly render using {{form}} via modelForm or Formsetfactory? I've taken a look at many documentation but none of them are really clear for my question and when I tried implementing the forms api like I said, it would only render one question. help greatly appreciated

EDIT:

When I tried to implement the forms API I used this method:

forms.py

```
blah_choices = [("1", "first"), ("2", "second")]
blah_choices2 = [("3", "third"), ("4", "four")]

class testRadioQuestions(forms.Form):
    q1 = forms.ChoiceField(label="Blah blah blah form question",
                           choices=(blah_choices),
                           widget=forms.RadioSelect()),
    q2 = forms.ChoiceField(label="blah blah some more form question",
                           choices=(blah_choices2),
                           widget=forms.RadioSelect())
```

view

```
def other_questionnaire(request):
     if request.method == "POST":
         print(request.body)
     return render(request, 'website/otherQuestions.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Are you using a Model? Show your view, and your form.

Comment: I tried using forms.Form. I can't seem to get a consistent set of questions with at least two radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a lot of work. I think the problem is probably that your view context only has the last form. You will need to create a list or a dictionary of forms. You will also need to differentiate their 'id' using a "[prefix](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms)".

I worked out a solution to this but (like you, I think) I have a lingering feeling that I missed something important in the 'forms' api.

My solution was to manually assign a prefix to each form that would allow me to to unpack it from the POST into the correct form subclass. I won't post all the different parts, but here's a sketch:

```
# forms.py
AnswerMap = { question_answer_type1 : FormClass1, etc etc }
def form_get(question, instance=None):
    answerform = AnswerMap[question.answer_type](instance=instance) # not sure this works, may need to handle two cases separately.
    return answerform 

def form_post(question, data, instance=None):
    answerform = AnswerMap[question.answer_type](data=data, instance=instance)
    if answerform.is_valid():
        return answerform
    else:
        pass  # handle error, I guess.
```

The next part is the view. The way I go through the request.POST here seems pretty inefficient, because I go through twice - first to collect prefixes and work out which questions are there, and a second time (in a single comprehension) collecting the data for each prefix.  But I haven't come up with anything better yet.

```
# views.py
class page_view(View):
    def get(self, page_no):
        forms = {}
        questions = Question.objects.filter(page=page_no)
        for question in questions:
            forms[question] = get_form_for_question(question, prefix=('q'+question.pk))
        self.context['forms'] = forms
        return render(request, template, context)

     def post(self, page_no)
         prefixes = []
         self.form_items = {}
         for key, value in request.POST.items():
             if key.startswith("q"):
                 q_number = re.search(r'q(\d+)#', key)
                 pk_q = int(q_number.group(1))  # the digits are the question primary key
                 prefix = 'q' + str(pk_q)
                 if prefix not in prefixes:
                     prefix.append(prefix)
                     question = Question.objects.get(pk=pk_q)
                     self.form_items[prefix] = {key: val for key,val in request.POST.items() if prefix in key}  # collects data for form; add any data that you don't render but will need in the database somewhere here - e.g. username or timestamp
                     form = form_post(value=self.form_items[prefix], question=question)
                     if form.is_valid():
                         form.save()
         return HttpRedirectResponse('as appropriate')
```

Add a custom template tag to unpack the form in the template:

```
# custom_tags.py
@register.filter
def get_item(dictionary, key):    
    return dictionary.get(key)
```

In a template, extract the form required something like this:

```
{% load 'custom_tags' %}
{% for question in page_question_set %}
     {{question}}
     {{ forms|get_item:question }}
{% endfor %}
```

I hope you find this useful.  I don't think its a bad workaround, but I remain worried that I'm working around something the framework can actually take care of.

Comment: Here's a simpler problem with a simple solution if you don't need the full general solution: http://www.joshuakehn.com/2013/7/18/multiple-django-forms-in-one-form.html

Comment: Wow this does seem pretty complex. I've got an intermediate understanding of it. I'll read up on how to implement this thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

**Just remove the <,>(comma) at the end of each defined field and this should work**

> forms.py

```
from django import forms

    blah_choices = [("1", "first"), ("2", "second")]
    blah_choices2 = [("3", "third"), ("4", "four")]

    class TestRadioQuestions(forms.Form):
        email = forms.EmailField()
        q1 = forms.ChoiceField(label="Blah blah blah form question",choices=(blah_choices),widget=forms.RadioSelect())
        q2 = forms.ChoiceField(label="blah blah some form question",choices=(blah_choices2),widget=forms.RadioSelect())
```

> views.py

```
def testRadioQuestions(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TestRadioQuestions(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('../../url_name')


    else:
        form = TestRadioQuestions()

    return render(request, 'template_url', {'form' : form })
```